# Formatting Number Outputs using Fixed Point decimal precision while still removing trailing Zeros? (Python 3.7.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x

***PYTHON 3.7.7***

For a school assignment, I have to submit code using an evil program called Mimir. Basically if my output is not pixel-perfect, I get a fail on the test case (15min writing a code, 50min making the output "look right").

***Question:***

I have no clue how to get my number outputs to look like the assignment's. My shown attempt here uses the 'g' format, as it is the only format modifier that removes trailing zeros and removes the decimal point when necessary. I need to be able to do this while maintaining a '.6' precision. Also, how do I make it that the output is never displayed in scientific notation.

Thank you for the help!

**MY CODE:**

```
#Asking user to define parameters for the calculation
Organs = float(input('Starting number of organisms: \n'))
DailyInc = float(input('Average daily increase: \n'))
DaysX = int(input('Number of days to multiply: \n'))

#Doing % to decimal calc. only one to make program work faster
Inc = (1 + (DailyInc / 100))

#Print table heading and first day
print('Day Approximate Population')
print('1', '             ', format(Organs, 'g'))

#Loop to calculate running daily total and print using format hell
for Day in range (2, DaysX + 1):
    Organs = Organs * Inc
    if Day >= 100:
        print(Day,"           ", format(Organs, 'g'))
    elif Day >= 10:
        print(Day,"            ", format(Organs, 'g'))
    else:
        print(Day,"             ", format(Organs, 'g'))
```

**MY OUTPUT (input - 2, 30, 60):**

```
Starting number of organisms: 
Average daily increase: 
Number of days to multiply: 
Day Approximate Population
1               2
2               2.6
3               3.38
4               4.394
5               5.7122
6               7.42586
7               9.65362
8               12.5497
9               16.3146
10              21.209
11              27.5717
12              35.8432
13              46.5962
14              60.575
15              78.7475
16              102.372
17              133.083
18              173.008
19              224.911
20              292.384
21              380.099
22              494.129
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT (input - 2, 30, 60):**

```
Starting number of organisms: 
Average daily increase: 
Number of days to multiply: 
Day Approximate Population
1               2
2               2.6
3               3.38
4               4.394
5               5.7122
6               7.42586
7               9.653618
8               12.549703
9               16.314614
10              21.208999
11              27.571698
12              35.843208
13              46.59617
14              60.575021
15              78.747528
16              102.371786
17              133.083322
18              173.008318
19              224.910814
20              292.384058
21              380.099275
22              494.129058
```

Comment: Instead of using spaces to format your data try `f'{val1:<17.15f}`. I'll post an example

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
val1 = 1.2635485547884475
val2 = 1.2

print(val1)
print(f'{val1:.2f}')
print(f'{val1:.6f}')
print(f'{val2:.6f}')
```

output:

```
1.2635485547884475
1.26
1.263549
1.200000
```

Comment: yes, thank you! But how can you change it so that the last value appears as 1.2?

Comment: unless you specifically format it as `:.1f` i dont believe it will automatically do that for you

Answer (score 0):

First example is displayed on a single line to demonstrate formating

```py
val1 = 1.2635485547884475
val2 = 1.2

print(f'{val1:<17.15f}', end = " ")
print(f'{val1:<7.5f}', end = " ")
print(f'{val2:<4.2g}')


print(f'{val1:<17.15f}')
print(f'{val1:<7.5f}')
print(f'{val2:<4.2g}')
```